# How to index a parent/child document into Elasticsearch using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am able to index easily with this curl command:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/prototype_2012.12.27/chow-clfg/Cg-IKkxdTstKAAAAlw-?parent=chow-demo' -d '{
  "chow-clfg": {
    "@type": "chow-clfg",
    "clfg": "Cg6h4VCcMexXAAAAsQc",
    "@timestamp": "2012-12-27T08:24:00.000Z",
    "count": 1
  }
}'
```

result:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "_index": "prototype_2012.12.27",
  "_type": "chow-clfg",
  "_id": "Cg-IKkxdTstKAAAAlw-",
  "_version": 1
}
```

This returns me a result almost instantaneously.

However when I try it with the nodejs' http.request method:

```
var http = require('http');
var index = "prototype_2012.12.27";
var server = "chow-clfg";

var options = {
 host: 'localhost',
 port: '9200',
 path: index+'/'+server+'/Cg-IKkxdTstKAAAAlw-?parent=chow-demo',
 method: 'PUT'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res){
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
     console.log(chunk);
    });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
 console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write('{"chow-clfg":{"@type":"chow-clfg","clfg":"Cg6h4VCcMexXAAAAsQc","@timestamp":"2012-12-27T08:24:00.000Z","count":1}}');
req.end;
```

This just suspends the process mid-way and it does not give me a feedback on whether it is successful or not. Also, when I search for the document in my index, I couldn't find it.

Therefore, is there a coding error that I have made? Or is there any way to rectify the problem?

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to call the req.end function, adding "()" to the last statement? Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `elasticsearch` module and it's `index` method with `parent` argument?